# customise jquery themes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

the jquery themes do not fit with my website design:

http://jsfiddle.net/6D5bw/

Is there an easy way to customise the theme without editing the original css file provided by jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this, but your answer was close enough. http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Answer (score 0):

yes! in the css you can find a comment that starts with:

```
* To view and modify this theme, visit...
```

there you can find a link to modify exactly your created theme with jQuery theme roller